# Recommended Software for Netbook (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, netbook

Which software is recommended for netbooks?

On my "normal" Windows machine (actually a VM) I use Visual Studio 2008, Delphi 2010 (beginning), Office 2008, and Delphi Prism 2010. But all those seem very heavy for a 1 GB netbook.

Can anyone recommend

a) a programming language/IDE that's really usable on a netbook (in case I travel with it and need some way to write a program or am simply bored (maybe this is a good excuse to learn Ruby)

b) a light-weight word processor/spreadsheet

for my little netbook (Atom N270, 1.6 GHz, 1 GB, 160 GB, Windows 7)?

I can buy software. It doesn't have to be freeware or open source.

Any other recommended software that makes a lot of sense on a 10" netbook?

I am thinking REALbasic might be light-weight enough. I have REALbasic. But I like any excuse to try something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Best lightweight IDE/Text Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173112/best-lightweight-ide-text-editor) @ Stack Overflow.
[Useful software for netbook?](https://superuser.com/questions/55364/useful-software-for-netbook) @ Super User.

Answer (score 0):

First admitting that I am not familiar with netbooks (but assume they are like laptops) I use the following:

a) a programming language/IDE: Lazarus - an open source clone of Delphi 7. I have it on both my Windows 10 desktop and Ubuntu laptop and find using it is very similar to using Delphi 7, which is great.

b) a light-weight word processor/spreadsheet: I use LibreOffice. Not sure how lightweight it is.  Do not like as well as MS Office (Primarily because of macros in the latter) but do not intend to shell out for a copy of Office form my Ubuntu machine

Hope this helps.

Comment: Netbooks generally have minimal hardware resources.  The concept is basically a browser that runs online apps.  You answered a very old question.  Site standards have changed since then and requests for software recommendations are now considered off-topic because they attract lists of personal preferences and opinions rather than facts and qualitative details, and the information gets dated quickly.